# What constitutes a call to the basic Google Maps JS api?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Just for background, I have an app which runs in both the browser and as a hybrid PhoneGap app, and which uses the Google Maps JS api.

Essentially, users pan and zoom the map and when a 'map idle' event is triggered, the app queries my API based on the current bounds of the idle map.

I'm just trying to find out what constitutes a call to the JS api?

- Does one map load/init equal one api call, regardless of how many times a user pans, scrolls and zooms the map?
- Or is each pan, scroll and zoom an api call (in other words, every time the map bounds are changed so new tiles need to be loaded?
- Or (worst case) is every new tile that needs to be loaded a separate call to the api?
- Or something else?

Anyone shed any light on this?

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_mapload):

A single map load occurs when:

- a map is displayed using the Maps JavaScript API v3 when loaded by a web page or application;
- a Street View panorama is displayed using the Maps JavaScript API v3 by a web page or application that has not also displayed a map;
- a SWF that loads the Maps API for Flash is loaded by a web page or application; or
- a single request is made for a map image from the Static Maps API.
- a single request is made for a panorama image from the Street View Image API.

**The degree to which a user interacts with a map once it has been loaded has no impact on the usage limits.**

Comment: Ah, ok. I missed that part! Thx.